# Ubuntu is "starting" and "finishing" stuff during boot-up

Tags: boot, hp

Today I moved to Ubuntu after almost 17 years of using windows.

Every time I turn off my laptop or restart it I get this long list that keeps starting and finishing tons of things that I have no clue about. It goes on for few minutes. Is it how Ubuntu normally boots up, or something is off?

[image]

Comment: Ubuntu boot should not last more than 20 seconds on a decent PC. Similarly, shutting down Ubuntu should take less than 10 seconds (unless there are some hung processes). After you boot your computer run the command `systemd-analyze blame` to see what is taking so long during boot.

Comment: This is what I received:
 
"Bootup is not yet finished (org.freedesktop.systemd1.Manager.FinishTimestampMonotonic=0).
Please try again later.
Hint: Use 'systemctl list-jobs' to see active jobs"

Comment: Please, do as the output suggests, and then [edit] your original question to add the extra information.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu is not a drop-in replacement for Windows. It's different. It works differently. It boots differently.

Your question seems to boil down to "*is this difference okay?*" If your system boots to a working desktop, then the difference is okay.

As a new user, you are going to encounter LOTS of differences. Embrace the changes.